# mongoose supplying upsert=true erroring out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose for the first time and declared my session model like below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var sessionSchema = new Schema({
    session_id : String,
    users : [{
        user_id : String,
        user_type : String,
    }],
    start_time : Date
});


var SessionInfo = mongoose.model('SessionInfo', sessionSchema);

module.exports = SessionInfo
```

Now I am trying to update the users array, whenever user joined my socket server with the same session id users detail should get updated

Below is the code for that

```
    newSession.update({session_id : sessionId},
    {$push: {users : 
        {user_id : userId, 
        user_type : userType}
    }},
    {safe: true, upsert: true},   
    function(err,model){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

But whenever client connects to the node js server I get below error

Tue Apr 28 2015 01:53:07 GMT+0530 (IST) Connection accepted.

/home/rahulshr/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1878
      oldCb(error, result ? result.result : { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 });
      ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Query.callback (/home/rahulshr/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1878:7)
    at /home/rahulshr/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:167:19
    at /home/rahulshr/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:103:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause, instead of calling update with instance of Session schema (newSession in this case) I should call it with SessionInfo